# sql edit save for log

Tags: sql-server

I want to know how to save edited values in sql server to return to it's value after that.

For example:

I have the user which it's status is working, after an year it's status is "Closed" the status is saved as an id in table user when it is working the id of status is 1 when it is closed i update the id to 2. how can I see that this user from date to date was working and now he is closed.

**Thanks for your replies.**

You got my question.

But the **problem** here is that I give here only one example which was user status, but the problem is that I have so many tables which I change they id's. For example I have Id of city, or Id of products etc.

If I save it at the same table of user for example I lost user id because every time I update user it will take a new id, or if I do a user status table I will do 20 or more tables like user status history. Also I want to save the text not only id's. For example the user got e new address I want to say from this date to date he was at previous address and now-days hi live in another place.

**Any suggestion please :).**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but I think you mean "I have a User table with a Status column, and I need to see a history of status changes because when I change the Status value for a specific user, I lose the previous value".

If that's correct, one simple solution is to add a second table called UserStatus or whatever, and INSERT a new row into it every time the user status changes. You can then easily see the complete history of status changes for each user, and you can also find the current status for any user by querying the 'newest' row for that user.

In principle, the Status column on the User table would be unnecessary if you add the UserStatus table, so you could remove it. If that isn't possible (e.g. you don't control the applications using the table), then you can add a trigger to the User table that populates the UserStatus table automatically when you UPDATE the Status.

Comment: You got my question.
But the problem here is that I give here only one example which was user status, but I have so many tables which I change they id's. For example I have Id of city, Id of products etc.

If I save it at the same table of user for example I lost user id because every time I update user it will take a new id, or if I do a user status table I will do 20 or more tables like user status. Also I want to save the text not only id's. For example the user got e new address I want to say from this date to date he was at previous address and now-days hi live in another place.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to have two columns

One is working/date and closed/date so that you can maintain the history of data.